# Is it possible to download all files of an application in Cloud Foundry?

Tags: cloud-foundry

Is it possible to download files of application to my local PC, i.e. perform operation opposite to "push"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I use this simple script to download all the log files in my app you can tweak it to get all the content within the app folder

```
    mkdir -p <appName>/app/data/logs
    for i in `cf files <appName> app/data/logs | awk '{print $1}'`; 
    do cf files <appName> app/data/logs/$i > <appName>/app/data/logs/$i; done
```

Comment: Apparently, this does not work any more (`cf version 6.12.2-24abed3-2015-07-15T14:20:44+00:00`). I am getting `cf: 'file' is not a registered command. See 'cf help'`

Answer (score 16):

As long as your application finished staging successfully (i.e. the build pack ran and finished), you should be able to download the droplet that was built by CF. That will contain amongst other things your application code.

Ex:

```
$ cf app <app-name> --guid
2836d5fe-35f7-4409-b27b-4ed308152bb4
$ cf curl /v2/apps/2836d5fe-35f7-4409-b27b-4ed308152bb4/droplet/download --output my-droplet
```

See also https://apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/2.6.0/apps/downloads_the_bits_for_an_app.html & http://v3-apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/version/3.50.0/#download-package-bits

**UPDATE (10/2/2019)**

Make sure you use the `--output` flag of `cf curl`. If you simply redirect the output of `cf curl` to a file, you will end up with an extra end of line character on the end of your droplet (or other download). For binary downloads this can cause problems. Some tools simply ignore the extra character like `tar`, but it will cause your app to fail if you upload a droplet using `cf push --droplet`.

---

**UPDATE (7/13/2018)**

There is also now `cf local`, which is a cf cli plugin that does several things.  One of the things it allows you to do is easily export and import droplets.  It's probably the easiest way to do this going forward.

https://github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/cflocal

Comment: I don't seem to have the `droplet` resource available: {
   "code": 10000,
   "description": "Unknown request",
   "error_code": "CF-NotFound"
}

Comment: Try this. Since this would respond back with 302. And curl did not follow the redirect. Find your access token from ~/.cf/config.json and do a "wget --header='Authorization: your token' https://api.run.pivotal.io/v2/apps/7f4bb926-49d0-491b-a092-a06f1ddb7263/droplet/download

Comment: Once you get this file to download, how do I open it? Doesn't seem to open as a `.zip`.

Comment: It's an archive, I can't recall if it's a zip or tar gzip.  If you run `file <name>` it'll tell you.  Or if you're on Windows, you could just try opening it with an archive/extraction app.  It'll probably detect the right format.

Comment: Thank you! The curl command was the only thing that worked for me on the `Diego` backend. For me (on Windows 7), the downloaded file was a tar ball (so, `tar xvzf my-droplet` will extract the files)

Comment: https://v3-apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/version/3.127.0/index.html#download-droplet-bits

Answer (score 9):

Recent versions of `cf` ([Cloud Foundry's command line interface](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/installcf/install-go-cli.html)) makes this simpler by using the **download plugin**: https://github.com/ibmjstart/cf-download

More details from one of the authors at http://blog.ibmjstart.net/2015/05/22/cf-download/

**Edit**
As pointed out by Dharmi, this does not work with the Diego backend https://github.com/ibmjstart/cf-download/issues/12

Comment: Thanks, this worked great, even though it sounded like my computer was going to explode.

Comment: cf-download wouldn't work if the app is running on the Diego backend.

Answer (score 2):

OK man. I had same trouble. The most simple way is SCP over SSH.

To turn this more simple as i can, i put the follow steps.

After all
I supose that you already had the "Cf cli" installed on your enviroment.
See how in: https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/cf-cli/install-go-cli.html

Now to login in Cloud foundry SSH we have some things to do:

1. Enable the ssh in you IBM app
2. Get the SSH host
3. Get the user
4. Get password

Step 01 - Enable SSH

See official references in: https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/ssh-apps.html

Open CMD or terminal write:

> **> cf login** - it's goes like bla bla bla
>
> **> cf enable-ssh app-name**
>
> > You realy want know the app name! It's basics...

Step 2 - Get the server host

Well... if i have to explain what is a ssh host, is better rollback from here. If not, run command (little joke):

> cf curl /v2/info
>
> > "app_ssh_endpoint": "ssh.MY-DOMAIN.com:2222"
> >
> > > Result is a json with many attributes.
> > >       Copy the field called "app_ssh_endpoint".
> > >       Take a look that after ":" is the ssh port to fill in the Winscp form or terminal command.

Step 3 - Concatenate you username

The username has made of "**cf:**" + "**GUID**" + "/" + "**InstanceID**".

To get GUID run terminal command:

> **cf app MY-AWESOME-APP --guid**
>
> > Return a long id like: abcdefab-1234-5678-abcd-1234abcd1234

The instance ID is the sequential number of you app instance. The first app instance becomes with "**0**".

So we have **cf:my-guid-result/0** as user name.

Step 4 - Get temp password

This step retrive a single use pass. Is this! You only use once the pass. Buuuut... you can execute this command every time that you would connect to the server or execute commands.

To get pass run terminal command:

> **cf ssh-code**
>
> > Return small password: abcdefab

After this i recomend:

If you desire to download a whole "app/" folder like me, compact this and download with winSCP graph interface or by terminal using "scp" command.

This isn't intuitive but it's possible to do. I wish you a good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this Ruby Gist a while back, it should still work with a small few tweaks or as is..

https://gist.github.com/danhigham/4705713