# Download the deployed War from cloud foundry

Tags: java, spring, cloud-foundry

Is there a way to download the deployed War from cloud foundry? I want to explode the war and check if the property files in the war are correct.

Comment: Why? You uploaded the war for deployment, why download it?

Comment: The code is fetched from git by an automated process maintained by a different team. The code is working fine locally , but I am suspecting that the process is not fetching necessary config files. Hence I thought of verifying it by downloading the war file built by the automated process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no direct way to download your application from a running cloud foundry container. However, you can use the `cf files <appname> [path]` command to explore and even download one file at a time.

```
cf files ramhellojava app
Getting files for app ramhellojava in org ....
OK

.java-buildpack/                             -
.java-buildpack.log                     136.3K
META-INF/                                    -
WEB-INF/                                     -
images/                                      -
index.html                                773B
index.js                                  1.1K
style.css                                 1.1K
```

Comment: To expand on Ram's answer, apps are not uploaded to CF in war/jar form. Any war, jar, or zip file provided to the cf CLI or other tooling is exploded and the exploded contents are uploaded one file at a time. Only the top level archive file is exploded, any jar files included in the archive are uploaded as-is.

Comment: Or you could use a plugin http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21421474/is-it-possible-to-download-all-files-of-an-application-in-cloud-foundry

Comment: Unfortunately I am using PCF 7.0 and the cf files command has been removed in this version.

Answer (score 3):

First thing...

> Is there a way to download the deployed War from cloud foundry?

The WAR file is not uploaded to Cloud Foundry.  The cf cli will look at the WAR file and extract everything from it.  It does not upload the file as a whole, but the individual files in it.  It's a minor difference, but worth noting because the WAR file itself doesn't exist on the server, just it's contents.

> I want to explode the war and check if the property files in the war are correct.

If you're looking for an individual file then as mentioned previously `cf files` is one way to go.  Alternatively you could use Eclipse w/the CF plugin.  That allows you to browse files via a GUI.

If you need lots of files or want the whole app, a better option is to download the droplet that's being used to run your app.  As long as your application finished staging successfully (i.e. the build pack ran and finished), you should be able to download the droplet that was built by CF.  That should contain amongst other things your application code.

Ex:

```
$ cf app <app-name> --guid
2836d5fe-35f7-4409-b27b-4ed308152bb4
$ cf curl /v2/apps/2836d5fe-35f7-4409-b27b-4ed308152bb4/droplet/download > my-droplet.tar.gz
```

Comment: Thank you so much , this helps!

Comment: Thanks. The file got saved in the home directory in MAC for me

Comment: cf curl command fails for me when using CF CLI v8.7.1. Looks like now the way to download droplet is the command [download-droplet](https://cli.cloudfoundry.org/en-US/v8/download-droplet.html): `$ cf download-droplet APP_NAME`

Comment: Yes, the v3 Cloud Controller API makes droplets a first class resources so you have better access to your droplets. The cf cli has commands, like you mentioned, interact with droplets.