# How to view contents of a PCF .droplet file in Windows?

Tags: cloud-foundry

**Problem**

The question pretty much says it all.  I used the plugin: "cf local" to get the .droplet file for my app in PCF.  However, I have no idea how to expand or view the contents of the file.

**What I tried**

- I tried adding a .zip at the end, but that did not work.
- I tried viewing in NotePad, but that did not work.

**Notes**

- We are using a Diego back-end which prevents us from using "cf files".
- It shouldn't matter but we are deploying a .NET application

Related: [Is it possible to download all files of an application in Cloud Foundry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21421474/is-it-possible-to-download-all-files-of-an-application-in-cloud-foundry)

Answer (score 2):

It's a gziped tar archive.  Try adding a `.tgz` or `.tar.gz` extension.  You may need a third party archive tool, I don't know if Windows will open that file by default.  7zip or something comparable should open it.

Answer (score 1):

Daniel was on the right track, however I wanted to post exactly what I used as an alternative to an extraction utility.

I found that the easiest way is to use bash, within Windows.  When we installed Github desktop there was an option to use bash and most of us, in my area, have done this.

*If you have already installed it then: Goto Preferences an choose your Git-Shell. Under default Shell you can choose between: CMD, Git Bash, Powershell or Custom.*

Once that is in place you can navigate to the folder where the .droplet file lives and execute the following command:

`tar -xvzf app-name.droplet`

This will extract the contents into a folder called "app" in the current directory which has the contents of your asset that would be in PCF.